# Trying to segue after tapping hashtag in UITextView from a UITableViewCell class

Tags: swift, uitableview, delegates, uitextview, segue

Using `URL.scheme` i'm getting the hashtag being tapped on in a `UITextView` inside a `UITableViewCell` class but i have two issues.

**First** how to segue from a cell class. I don't have `perform` segue function. Only found in the `UITableView` class.

**Second** how to send the hashtag name or the mention name to the new `UIViewController`. I can use delegate methods or send it through perform segue. But again how will i segue from the cell class.

The next code is written in the `UITableViewCell` class

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {

    let path = URL.absoluteString
    switch URL.scheme! {
    case "hash" :
        let hash = path.removingPercentEncoding?.components(separatedBy: ":").last
        print(hash!) // ---> Retriving tapped on hash name correctly

    case "mention" :
        let mention = path.removingPercentEncoding?.components(separatedBy: ":").last
        print(mention!) // ---> Retriving tapped on mention name correctly
    default:
        print("Just a regular link \(path.removingPercentEncoding!)")
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several different ways of doing this, but I would probably use a custom delegate protocol. Define the protocol in your cell file as follows:

```
protocol MyTableViewCellDelegate: class {
    func myTableViewCell(_ cell: MyTableViewCell, shouldSelectHashTag tag: String)
}
```

Add a property to your table view cell class:

```
class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    // make sure the property is `weak`
    weak var delegate: MyTableViewCellDelegate?
}
```

I'm assuming your table view data source is also the view controller from which you want to perform the segue. Make this view controller conform to the new protocol:

```
extension MyViewController: MyTableViewCellDelegate {
    func myTableViewCell(_ cell: MyTableViewCell, shouldSelectHashTag tag: String) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "MyHashTagSegue", sender: tag)
    }
}
```

Assign your view controller as the delegate of the table view cell inside the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` data source method:

```
let cell: MyTableViewCell = <dequeue the cell>
cell.delegate = self
```

Finally, don't forget to call the delegate method from your table view cell:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
    let tag = <get the hash tag> 
    delegate?.myTableViewCell(self, shouldSelectHashTag: tag)
}
```

Comment: Great answer and i think it will work. But my ViewController is in a different story board than the one i'm trying to segue to. How do you think i can solve this issue<...??

Comment: You can use a storyboard reference. This is another object you can drag into your storyboard just like a view controller, and you can attach a segue to it.

Comment: Yes this is what i did i instantiateViewController to the storyboard i choose and it worked. Thanks :))